# Asp.net passing parameter to a usercontrol is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

On one of my `usercontrol(form.ascx)` I am adding another `usercontrol(EntryForm.ascx)` like this:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/layouts/Form/EntryForm.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="EntryForm" %>
<uc:EntryForm  id="EntryForm" runat="server" formId='<%#Id%>'/>
```

but on `EntryForm.ascx.cs`, I am getting null for `formId`.

Don't get null if I do:

```
<uc:EntryForm  id="EntryForm" runat="server" formId="123"/>
```

A bit more detail:

code for `form.ascx.cs`

```
protected string Id {get;set;}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Id = //some logic and settings this id with a value from Database
}
```

Comment: I think you should read about the [Life Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net/4948/page-life-cycle) of asp.net. Basically `Page_Load` of the UserControl has already been completed by the time you call `DataBind` on the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass parameter by this way. You can do it like this:

**Child (EntryForm.ascx)**

```
public partial class EntryForm
{
   public string formId { set; get; }
}
```

**Parent (form.ascx)**

**Mark up**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhEntryForm" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

**Code behind**

```
private string Id {get;set;}
```

You can use this method with load child user control:

```
private void LoadEntryForm()
        {
            this.plhEntryForm.Controls.Clear();
            EntryForm child = this.LoadControl(this.ControlPath + "EntryForm.ascx") as EntryForm;
            if (child != null)
            {
                child.formId = this.Id; // Pass formId from parent to child               
                child.ID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.ControlPath + "EntryForm.ascx"); // You should set EntryForm.ascx path in your project
                this.plhEntryForm.Controls.Add(child);
            }
        }
```